# File association - modify shell's edit verb on Vista

Tags: registry, windows-vista, windows-shell, file-association

I'm looking to programmatically modify the **edit** verb for the shell on Vista. For example, I want right click edit (in explorer) to open a .cs file w/ Notepad++.

How do I change a file association on Windows Vista?

Comment: This is really an OS configuration question in my opinion.

Comment: OK. So which part are you having trouble with? You haven't asked a *question*.

Comment: My question is how to change the shell's edit file association on a Vista machine?

Comment: Great. *Now* I think it looks like a programming question.

Comment: Ehh...you have completely changed the intent of the question that was asked. The OP never said anything about doing this programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need Administrative login for that, since you have to modify HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Find the registry key associated with .cs files; you'll find a description like "C# Source Code File" (although probably not that; I'm not on a machine with VS installed right now to check). That key will point you to another one (with MS, it's usually a GUID) which is where the settings for edit, open, and so forth are stored; that's where you'll need to make your changes.

That should get you started, unless Rob guessed wrong and you didn't mean "programmatically modify" in the first place. :-)

Comment: Thanks Ken, 

I was able to get this to work by copying the Open key format located in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cs.9.0\shell\ and create a sibling Edit key.